# How can indexing be used to access elements in a queue in python?

Tags: python, indexing, queue

I made a queue to store some values of distance. Now, I want to access the element in the queue with its index. How can I do this? I tried something as shown in the code below but it displayed an error saying " Queue instance has no attribute '**getitem**'".

```
myqueue =Queue(maxsize = 10)

myqueue.put(data.transform.translation.y)

print("queue = %f", myqueue[0])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not. Because it is not a sequence. If you want to index it, probably make a `list`. For a queue `q`, `list(q)` won't work as `q` is not iterable. "Indexing" a queue has no meaning sematically. All the relevant operations `put`, `get`, checking empty/full, current size are all available as methods. So if such a need arises you probably need another data-structure.

Comment: you are right that indexing a "queue" has no meaning, but it's not hard to implement a data structure that has both `push_front` and `pop_back` as well as "indexing" all in O(1), e.g. [C++ deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/). So my question is, have you every seen such an implementation in Python?

Comment: @FarzadAbdolhosseini There is a "deque" class in "collections" module. Just import it by "from collections import deque".

Comment: @whoAmI Yes, but it doesn't support "indexing" in O(1): "Indexed access is O(1) at both ends but slows to O(n) in the middle".
Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque